# Type error: Cannot read property 'configure' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I have the following error: 
Cannot read property 'configure' of undefined.
How can I make my unit test work.

this is my unit test so far :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Enzyme, mount } from 'enzyme'
import layout from './layout';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15';


//Unit Test  V
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe ('layout />', () => {
it( 'should be defined ', () => {
  expect(layout).toBeDefined()
 })

it( 'should render ', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<layout />)
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
})

it( 'should render class name', () => {
    const wrapper = mount
    (<div className = "empty-layout"/>)
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

});

I expect the test to pass. Any ideas/hints or improvements that I could implement on my unit test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `configure` step is always done globally in a file called `setupTests.js` which is usually at the root of your project:

`setupTests.js`:

```
import {configure} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({adapter: new Adapter()});
```

see here: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests#src-setuptestsjs

So create a file `setupTests.js` in the root folder of your project with the provided content above and remove the line `Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });` from your test and see if it works.

Comment: Mis94 , I just realized I did not import {configure} from 'enzyme';  Thanks. Any ideas that I could use on my test ?

Comment: Are you still facing same error, or your tests pass now?

Comment: The test is passing at the moment. So pretty much is just checking if the function is working and getting called right ??

Comment: Yes, as of Enzyme 3, you will need to install Enzyme along with an `Adapter` corresponding to the version of React you are using and the function `configure` is used to configure enzyme to use the adapter you want it to use.

Comment: Its already installed. I was getting an error before  because I did not import configure from 'enzyme'.  So knowing that the function is getting called and working,  I have 2 questions : 1) should I add an extra input To pass and fail it ? 2)Should I use the same set up for other files, sorta like a template

Comment: Concerning you first question, actually I can't get it, so it would be better if you post it as a new question with more details. Concerning your second question, the answer is yes. You should create a single file `setupTests.js` in your `src` folder of the project as described in the link I've added in the answer, after that you don't have to make any configurations in your test code files.

Comment: I will take a look at the file, thanks. I'm not sure if its correct what I have so far. So the code above : check if the function is getting called , also if its working. Therefore the unit test PASSES at the moment.  How could I add another  "IT STATEMENT"  to make the function Fail for example

Comment: You can see examples here:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/testing-react-components-with-enzyme-and-jest#toc-shallow-rendering
https://medium.com/codeclan/testing-react-with-jest-and-enzyme-20505fec4675
Generally what I prefer is to define what's called "test suite" inside a single `describe` then inside that `describe` write multiple cohesive (related) tests using `it ` statements, say a test suite per component. But the style of writing tests is something optional and you can see as many examples as you can then agree with your team to a suitable style and stick to it.

Comment: I was able to figure out and understand a bit more testing lately. But thanks for the help and assistance